# Thunderbird remove buttons

Tags: thunderbird

I'm using thunderbird 78.4.2. How to remove the buttons circles in red in the following image?
[image: buttons to remove]

Comment: when I hover the mouse over one of the buttons and right-click, I get "Customize..." and can remove buttons. But I have Linux and Thunderbird 68.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there seems to be no longer a build-in way to remove the redundant buttons, however there is an addon which allows to customise which buttons are displayed. If all of them are removed the toolbar is no longer visible.

https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-GB/thunderbird/addon/msghdr-toolbar-customize/

(caveat: even invisible the toolbar will still require some space, so the time information remains in the second line)