# Thunderbird: remove icons (reply, forward, archive ..) from message header toolbar

Tags: email, thunderbird, css

How can I remove the useless icons (reply forward archive ..) from message header toolbar?

[image]

it used to be possible to "customize" the panel, but not anymore in thunderbird 102

I am alredy customizing omni.ja, so I wouldn't mind if it involves commenting something out in the code.

Otherwise, I alredy have userChrome.css and userContent.css, so if there is some trick to disable it there, that would be fine as well

Comment: https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/thunderbird/addon/msghdr-toolbar-customize/

Comment: duplicate of: https://superuser.com/questions/1601028/thunderbird-remove-buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than having to install yet another addon, just to make simple customization, the following can be added to `userChrome.css`:

```
.header-buttons-container {
    display:none !important;
}
```

source: https://www.reddit.com/r/Thunderbird/comments/1558ibi/hide_the_toolbar_in_the_message_header/

Really, what's wrong with people suggesting an addon to every customization request. Like seriously, am I to install 100 addons just to get rid of the evil, useless buttons?

Especially when it has simple clean solution by customizing `userChrome.css`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Gantendo, you can use an add-on.  In particular [Message Header Toolbar Customize](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/thunderbird/addon/msghdr-toolbar-customize/)

> **About this Add-on**
> Thunderbird 78 removes customize functionality of message header view toolbar. This add-on reproduces the feature on Thunderbird 78.
>
> You can do the followings:
>
> - Change icon display: Icons beside text, Icons only or Text only
> - Change order of toolbar buttons
> - Hide unnecessary buttons
> - Add spacer and separator
> - Add Conversation, Tag and Forward As buttons, which removed from Thunderbird 78

**But note, that it does not say that it works in the latest thunderbird.  It does work in 102.**