# How to remove individual header buttons in Thunderbird?

Tags: email, thunderbird, gui, user-interface, css

In Thunderbird there are solutions to hide *all* header buttons (from the message header pane): [here](https://superuser.com/q/1802457) and [here](https://superuser.com/q/1601028).

But how can I just hide *individual* header buttons?

I would like to hide the "junk" button, because I never use it:

[image: screenshot]

I have [found an add-on](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/msghdr-toolbar-customize/) which does the job, but I'd rather use userChrome/CSS instead.